# Aspose Java PDF Add Signature Field

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.pdf

Using Aspose Java PDF does anyone know how to add a PDF signature field to an existing template? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shaun, In order to add Signature field, please try using following code snippet.

```
//Open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document("Input.pdf");

//Create a field
SignatureField signatureField = new SignatureField(pdfDocument.getPages().get_Item(1), new com.aspose.pdf.Rectangle(100, 200, 300, 300));
signatureField.setPartialName("signature1");

//Add field to the document
pdfDocument.getForm().add(signatureField, 1);

//Save modified PDF
pdfDocument.save("Output.pdf");
```

However if you need to add digital signature in existing PDF file, please follow the instructions specified over [Add Digital Signature to PDF File](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfjava/Add+Digital+Signature+to+PDF+File)

My name is Nayyer and I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.